# UITabBarController > UISplitViewController > UINavigationController create issue

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a question regarding to the the `UINavigationController` inside `UISplitViewController` inside `UITabBarController`. Basically, the structure of my app looks like this.

```
Window 
---UITabBarController
------UISplitViewController
---------UINavigationController (detail)
---------UINavigationController (master)
------UISplitViewController 
---------UINavigationController (detail)
---------UINavigationController (master)
------UISplitViewController
---------UINavigationController (detail)
---------UINavigationController (master)
```

When I select something on detail page, it just show on master page which it works just fine. However, the problem comes when I select something on master page to push to the next view controller and press back button, the view is pop back but it is like it is done by using `dismissModalViewController` (the whole screen is pulling down including the detail area). The problem is only come on the horizontal screen mode. It pops back like it should be done (left to right) if the screen is on vertical mode.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? Struggling with the same thing... been googling for two days and no answer..

Comment: Yes. You need to add -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation in your controllers.

Comment: If this is the solution why not create an answer and accept it?

Comment: @BlackMojo Exact same problem here as well. To which controllers do we need to add that code to? The entire hierarchy? I only support landscape views, so have that function implemented in the root tab controller, which nicely restricts the app to landscape only. I wouldn't think it needed to be added to any of the child controllers...???